# "Shared wallets will not work correctly."

Tags: wallet

One [satoshi bones rule](http://bitzillions.com/satoshibones/rules) states:

```
SHARED WALLETS WILL NOT WORK CORRECTLY.
```

What is a shared wallet? Why would shared wallets not work correctly with satoshi bones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared wallet is often what online services and exchanges often use. They aren't fully functional wallets, and rely on a backend service to manage funds across users, this is the "sharing".

The reason you can't send from a shared address is because shared wallets only allow 1-way transactions due to technical limits. Satoshi Bones sends back bitcoins to the address it receives from after betting from what I'm assuming.

You're using a shared wallet if your sending from an exchange, Coinbase, and most online wallets or websites. The only web wallet that is not a shared wallet that I know is blockchain.info. Else just use wallets you install like Bitcoin-qt, Armory, or Electrum. I recommend Electrum.

Comment: I think you are misrepresenting these as not fully functional wallets. Using the input's consumed coins' previous address as this (and other) sites do, is a hack, cannot be guaranteed to work, and relies on the discouraged practice of reusing addresses. Bitcoin transactions simply don't have a reliable "from" address, and if you want to send coins somewhere, you should first ask where to send it to.